# Is it currently possible to create a tvOS in app purchase record on iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, tvos

I'm trying to develop a tvOS game with an in app purchase, but it appears that the only options in iTunes Connect for creating iap items are for iOS and Mac apps - There don't appear to be anything directing towards tvOS.

I have tried using the iOS app of this game on iTunes Connect with the same bundle ID to get those items listed in game, but all I get back from Apple's servers is an empty array.

StoreKit is available for tvOS and the code builds and seems to run just fine. Have they even updated iTunes Connect to handle this stuff yet?

Comment: Please give me the idea, if you are doing InApp purchase for the TVOS application using TVML and TVJS In SWIFT. My problem is that, there is no any TVML template for the InApp purchase. So that I need the idea to do InApp for this scenario. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StoreKit is not available if you're testing on the simulator.

From [tvOS 9.1 beta 2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/download/):

> **Note**: StoreKit (that is, In-App Purchase) does not work in Simulator.